# Want to use "xcrun simctl" in Appium automation

Tags: ios, appium, instruments, xcrun, simctl

Is there a way I can use `xcrun simctl` commands in my Appium automation? I have came to situation where I wanted to use uninstall and install app from simulator which is not available with appium methods. So, I am thinking if somehow I could use this utility in automation code.

I am running my automation on iOS in Java.

Comment: Have you tried starting the appium server with --full-reset option, I think that option will remove the app after the tests

Comment: Also feel free to submit a pull-request to Appium, to add the feature you need. Appium uses simctl for some things already: https://github.com/appium/node-simctl

Comment: Thanks.. @BalajiSekar Yes I have been using full-reset till now but my app code is creating problem if full reset simulator.

Comment: @TinyTimZamboni Yes, I think this is something unique I wanted. I am thinking of collaborating there.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class XCRunUtil {

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();

Process process;

public void execute(String url) {
    String link = "xcrun simctl list devices";
    System.out.println("link : " + link);
    processBuilder.command("sh", "-c", link);
    try {
        process = processBuilder.start();

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        // Read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

This above code will works